# What data do I have to use to generate a QR code for Google Authenticator?

Tags: node.js, qr-code, google-authenticator

I want to utilize the [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2) app for login purposes in our application.

I'm using [speakeasy](https://github.com/markbao/speakeasy) to generate the base data for the authentication. It can also spit out a URL to a Google website that generates a QR code which I can scan with Google Authenticator to set up the scheme.

I want to generate the QR code myself, mainly because I want to display it in the console using [qrcode-terminal](https://github.com/gtanner/qrcode-terminal).

What data do I have to encode in the QR code to make it work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The string you have to encode is:

```
otpauth://totp/ApplicationName?secret= + key.base32
```

- `ApplicationName` is the name of your application that you want to have displayed in Google Authenticator.

Your implementation would look something like this:

```
var key = speakeasy.generate_key( {length : 20} );
qrcode.generate( "otpauth://totp/foo?secret=" + key.base32, function( qrcode ) {
  console.log( qrcode );
} );
```

There's also [official documentation](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/Key-Uri-Format) available on the format.

Comment: When you want to use custom periods (longer or shorter than the default 30 seconds) you're going to want to use a different OTP app, like [FreeOTP](https://fedorahosted.org/freeotp/).

Answer (score 2):

> What data do I have to encode in the QR code to make it work?

Google Authenticator has a [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/wiki/). The [KeyUriFormat](https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/wiki/KeyUriFormat) has the following example:

> Provision a TOTP key for user "alice@google.com", to use with a
>   service provided by Example, Inc:
>
> otpauth://totp/Example:alice@google.com?secret=JBSWY3DPEHPK3PXP&issuer=Example
>
> This Base32 encoded key "JBSWY3DPEHPK3PXP" has the value:
>
> `byte[] key = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!', (byte) 0xDE, (byte) 0xAD, (byte) 0xBE, (byte) 0xEF };`

Its important to use the company name ("Example") in both the beginning and the end (with the issuer). See [ConflictingAccounts](https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/wiki/ConflictingAccounts) for details.

Comment: That's the same article I linked to

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I missed it. It looks like your answer is missing the part about conflicting accounts from the docs.